# There is no Debug Remote JS item in the developer menu, but I have the Open JS Debugger item. How can I find Debug Remote JS?

Tags: react-native, expo, remote-debugging, javascript-debugger

There is no Debug Remote JS item in the developer menu in Android, but I have the Open JS Debugger item. But before I had Debug Remote JS item and lost it. How can I find Debug Remote JS ?

Don't work "jsEngine": "jsc" in json file under ios and android.

Comment: Issue closed, resolved.